# Difference between usage of ‘удивление’ и ‘сюрприз’

Tags: словоупотребление

I was given this sentence:
Я делаю сюрприз (Im preparing a surprise)
But i was also given удивление as when you pop out and yell surprise* 
What is the difference of usage between the two, i searched online but there was nothing there.

Comment: удивление - surpise in the sense you get 'something u not expect happens' (E.g. Surprise was on her face), сюрприз - surpise in the sense 'a unexpected gift' (as in 'we have a surpise for you). Hence confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These words are completely different and are not interchangeable.

**Сюрприз** - an unexpected event or piece of information.

**Удивление** - a state of being astonished, a feeling caused by something unexpected.